# Split words only if last letter matches a specific char

Tags: php, explode

I am using this php function in order to split the array as soon a ":" is used:

```
$headline = 'Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit';
var_dump( explode( ':', $headline ) );
```

I need to modify the code so that if the ":" is within a word, it doesn't explode, for example:

```
$headline = 'Lorem:ipsum: dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit';
var_dump( explode( ':', $headline ) );
```

Desired Result:

```
Lorem:ipsum:
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
```

So it should only explode if the : is at the end of a word. Thanks for any help!

I've tried it by using if (\str_ends_with but with no success (I'm a PHP noob).

Comment: How do you identify that it's at the end of a word?

Comment: You can do `explode( ': ', $headline )` (added a space after the colon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you can use the [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) PHP function that uses a regex as delimiter:

```
$headline = 'Lorem:ipsum: dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit';
print_r(preg_split("/:[^\w]/", $headline));
```

The regex `:[^\w]` means "a : not followed by a word character".

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem:ipsum
    [1] => dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
)
```

Try it here https://onlinephp.io/c/64e18

Comment: This depends on OP wants to (or can) use regexs.

Comment: This is working perfectly (in my WordPress template). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've modified it by using: return(preg_split("/:[^\w]/", $headline, 2));
So that only the first occurence is matched. Thank you!